# Cannot read property 'chooseDesktopMedia' of undefined

Tags: webrtc, screensharing

I am working on desktopCapture API of google chrome webrtc. When I run the application I am getting error **"Cannot read property 'chooseDesktopMedia' of undefined"**. Means browser is not able to find the chrome.desktopCapture inside chrome browser.

My chrome browser version is 38.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, access to the [desktopCapture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture) is disabled by default. You either need to write an extension or modify the browsers internal flags.

[I wrote such an example extension which might be helpful.](https://github.com/wpp/ScreenStream)