# when chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia will be available in chrome (without using plugins)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screen-capture, screencast

I need to make screencasting + audio and than making videos from them for further download to server (without using extensions / plugins)

As I now, the only way to start showing screen in chrome  is via - chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia ( If I am not right, please correct me )

[Cannot read property 'chooseDesktopMedia' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018571/cannot-read-property-choosedesktopmedia-of-undefined) - I've read answer to  this question and there was said that this (chrome.desktopCapture) API can be used:
- via some extension
- or by enabling browsers internal flags (As I Know - flag for showing screen isn't available for more then two years after creating of this api - If I am not right, please correct me )
 Maybe there is a need to enable some another flags to use this api? I'd made a research - and didn't find which ones.

So,

1. Is it possible to start screencasting without using plugins and without asking user to enable some flags(if they exist) ?
2. If not, maybe, somebody knows when this functionality will be available in chrome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 No; Screen capturing from chrome requires the [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrtc-desktop-sharing/nkemblooioekjnpfekmjhpgkackcajhg) or the command-line flag(--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing)

2 No; not until the mindset changes.

The chrome developers consider screen capturing a big security hole (because to many users click yes to all security prompts). They are making it harder to use intentionally. SSL is [required](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins) for it and related (webrtc).

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Do you now if there is any official chrome rosource to which I can sign up and know about it (desktopCapture without extensions), as soon it will be possible?

Comment: you could setup a filter to review the commits on the source code and notify you~